# Webpoller found a running server at http://localhost:8080

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am new to jboss.Currently i have jboss in running state whenever i am trying to run it in debug mode i am getting the error prompt as in the below image.even when i click on stop button it gets stopped but again on clicking start button it says it's already running.

Please help

Regards,
Manish[image]

Comment: I am able to see image in my post.

Comment: @nidhin are u not able to see the image in the post ?

Comment: may be my firewall blocking it.

Comment: have you soloved this issue?